# Plugging in American standard 240 V into a European standard 240 V machine

Tags: ac, mains

I made the mistake today of not checking if the voltages were correct from an isolation transformer that converters American single phase 240 V (phase, phase, ground) to European 240 V (phase, neutral, ground). I never shorted one of the phases to ground on the secondary side. The machine turned on; some of the machine had power, but without any computer hooked up I can't tell if it was fully functional. The correct voltages should be as follows:

The machine is a soldering rework station Ersa HR550

- Phase to ground = 240 V (should be 230 V +/- 10%)
- Phase to neutral = 240 V (should be 230 V +/- 10%)
- Ground to neutral = 0 V (should be 0 V)

When I measured it was:

- Phase to ground = 120 V (should be 230 V +/- 10%)
- Phase to neutral = 240 V (should be 230 V +/- 10%)
- Ground to neutral = 120 V (should be 0 V)

I have no way of knowing if I fried any of the internals or if it would be protected in some way. Any insight is appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide a wiring diagram 0f your setup. It would probably be useful to post the specs of the transformer and your appliance. You are asking us to give you advice on both a safety and usage problem based on little information. In any case, you should probably move this question to the Home Improvement stack exchange since it is more appropriate to them.

Comment: Sounds like a center tapped secondary. Why the transformer in the first place? What kind of machine is it?

Comment: Unless your machine explicitly requires neutral to be grounded, the transformer is unnecessary. Considering that many European mains outlets are reversible, your machine in all likelihood doesn't care.

Comment: Commonly isolation transformers are used for isolation, so it would not have a ground pin on output, or ground one of the transformer outputs to make it the neutral. What kind of transformer you have and how it is connected? @brhans if the transformer has earth and just fully isolated output, the AC potential can float at any voltage as it is not ground referenced, which can cause problems, like spikes exceeding safe voltage between ground and mains wires.

Answer (score 3):

In all likelihood (99.9%) nothing is fried. Appliances aren't supposed to connect ground to neutral or assume ground is connected to neutral. In fact as brhans pointed out, a whole lot of European plugs *are reversible* so "European-style 240V" could well have 0V phase-to-ground and 240V neutral-to-ground if you plug them in backwards! And the plugs are completely symmetrical, so there's no way to tell which way is backwards. Half of all the appliances in Europe are probably plugged in backwards right now, and nobody notices or cares.

Stands to reason that anything in between should also be okay, including the American-style split-phase 240V, so I don't think you need this transformer. (Mandatory disclaimer: I am a random fellow Internet user, and not legally liable in case for *some really weird reason* it does go pop)

It would be a problem if, for example, the computer connected neutral to ground, but it can't do that, or else it would explode half the time in Europe, shock you half the time in Europe, trip GFCIs everywhere, and in rare circumstances, catch fire because of wiring problems in completely different rooms in your house.

I gather you're talking about a desktop computer. Everything on the low-voltage side of the computer's power supply is grounded to ground, not neutral. That includes the metal case and all the cables.

If it's a laptop, everything on the low-voltage side isn't grounded at all, neither to neutral nor ground.

Comment: The laptop could be grounded via any other connected device, such as via display cable, network cable, or USB cable.

Comment: I added some more information in my post that might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

In North America 240V for residential is between two phase, called line voltage. Your measuring is correct. Neutral is not official name, in code it is called dedicated wire. It is wire, usually connected to ground at source for protection purpose. Most of devices are not sensitive if phase switched with neutral, so if you machine does not required special connection it will be OK.